# Countable set in constructive mathematics

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

Let $A$ be an alphabet (i.e. a set of symbols) and suppose that $A$ is countable.

Let $X$ be the set of all the words (i.e. finite strings) that I can write using the alphabet $A$.

Can I prove **in constructive mathematics** that $X$ is countable?

Comment: Assuming the elements of $A$ are indexed, you can give an explicit index function for the elements of $X$

Comment: Ok, but how can I give the index function for the elements of $X$?

Comment: If you say $a=1,b=2,c=3$ etc. you take the $2^{k-1}$ entries which sum to $k$ before the $2^k$ which sum to $k+1$.  One way to do this would be to write $n$ in binary and read the number of binary digits of a $1$ followed by $0$s; for example for the $94$th case you would look at $1001110_2$ and split this as $100-1-1-10$ counting it as $3-1-1-2$ digits and so the word $caab$ - this is easily reversible and this is obviously a bijection.

Comment: So, if I consider a propositional language L with a countable set of atomic propositions and a finite number of connectives I can prove that the set of all the propositions of the language L is countable, right?

Comment: I believe we can construct a bijection between the sets of natural numbers and the set of finite string of natural numbers even over $\mathsf{PRA}$ with the intuitionistic logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can indeed prove this.

First, fix a particular bijection $f : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$. The usual construction works constructively.

Now use this to recursively construct bijections $f_j : \mathbb{N}^j \to \mathbb{N}$ for all $j \geq 1$. In particular, for $k \geq 1$, we define $f_{k + 1}(x_1, \ldots, x_k, x_{k + 1}) = f(f_k(x_1, \ldots, x_k), x_{k + 1})$. And of course we define $f_1(x) = x$.

Now consider strings over $\mathbb{N}$; let $\mathbb{N}^*$ be the set of such strings. Then we can explicitly define a bijection $g : \mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ by

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & x = \emptyset \\
  f(f_k(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_k), k) + 1 & x = x_1 x_2 \ldots x_k, \; k > 0
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $\mathbb{N}^*$ is countably infinite. In fact, we’ve explicitly constructed an enumeration of it.

Now fix an injection $i : A \to \mathbb{N}$. Then $i$ induces the injection $i^* : A^* \to \mathbb{N}^*$ defined by $i^*(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_k) = i(x_1) i(x_2) \ldots i(x_k)$. Then $g \circ i^* : A^* \to \mathbb{N}$ is an injection, so $A^*$ is countable.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Can we use this idea also for proving that for a propositional language with a countable set of atomic propositions and five connectives ($\wedge$,$\vee$,$\neg$,$\rightarrow$,$\leftrightarrow$) the set of all the propositions is countable?

Comment: @effezeta Yes. In particular, we can identify propositions with strings over a certain alphabet which includes the atomic propositions, connectives, and parentheses, so it actually follows directly from this proposition. We can even ditch the parentheses by using prefix or postfix notation.